# Pegar a id do usuário logado

Tags: php, laravel

Como faço para pegar a id do usuário logado e inserir na tabela junto com description e title? Imagino que seja bem simples.

```
public function saveCallRegister()
{
     $title = Request()->input('title');
     $description = Request()->input('description');

     DB::insert('INSERT INTO feeds (title, description) VALUES (?, ?)', array($description, $title));

     return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para pegar o `id` do usuário logado:

```
Auth::user()->id
```

Isso se você estiver utilizando a `guard` que vem por default.